# Numbers: How do I write between in an IF statement?

Tags: numbers

I can't get the following formula to work in Apple's Numbers.app. I need the second `IF` to be `BETWEEN 33.3% AND 66.6%`.

This is what I have tried but it does not work:

```
IF(D≥66.6%,"High","")&IF(D>33.3%<66.6%,"Medium","")&IF(D≤33.3%,"Low","")
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
IF(D≥66.6%,"High",IF(D<=33.3%,"Low","Medium"))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried something similar to this, but unfortunately it still includes the second If when the first is met. I.e. all High percentages show as HighMedium.

I just tried this...
`IF(D≥66.6%,"High","")&IF((D>33.3%)+(D<66.6%),"Medium","")&IF(D≤33.3%,"Low","")`
It works but it shows a blue triangle with "The formula uses a Boolean in place of a number."

Comment: This way works. Check the images. The only way to put two (or more) `IF` statements in the same cell is when they are nested.

Comment: Ah thanks jherran! I still had the & operator between Ifs, I've just realised :) It works perfectly, thank you!